# How to Convert string "00h:03m:30s:793ms" to TimeSpan in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string in XML which specifies the duration and the format is "00h:03m:30s:793ms"

How can i parse this to TimeSpan format in c#?

I have tried following but none of them works

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact("00h:03m:30s:793ms", "hh:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out testCaseData.duration)

TimeSpan.TryParseExact("00h:03m:30s:793ms", "hh':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out testCaseData.duration)
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.totimespan.aspx

Comment: You have to match the format string to your expected input string, including all literals, and of course delimiting the literals correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(
    "00h:03m:30s:793ms",
    "hh'h:'mm'm:'ss's:'fff'ms'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    out testCaseData.duration);
```